# Maximum weighted bipartite matching, constraint: ordering of each graph is preserved

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Let's say I have two sets: (n_1, n_2, ...) and (m_1, m_2, ...) and a matching function match(n, m) that returns a value from 0 to 1. I want to find the mapping between the two sets such that the following constraints are met:

- Each element must have at most 1 matched element in the opposite set.
- Unmatched elements will be paired with a dummy element at cost 1
- The sum of the match function when applied to all elements is maximal
- I am having trouble expressing this formally, but if you lined up each set parallel to each other with their original ordering and drew a line between matched elements, none of the lines would cross. E.x. [n_1<->m_2, n_2<->m_3] is a valid mapping but [n_1<->m_2, n_2<->m_1] is not.

(I believe the first three are standard weighted bipartite matching constraints, but I specified them in case I misunderstood weighted bipartite matching)

This is relatively straight forward to do with an exhaustive search in exponential time (with respect to the size of the sets), but I'm hoping a polynomial time (ideally O((|n|*|m|)^3) or better) solution exists.

I have searched a fair amount on the "assignment problem"/"weighted bipartite matching" and have seen variations with different constraints, but didn't find one that matched or that I was able to reduce to one with this added ordering constraint. Do you have any ideas on how I might solve this? Or perhaps a rough proof that it is not solvable in polynomial time (for my purposes, a reduction to NP-complete would also work)?

Comment: sorry ordering is not simplification. You have sequences as input or sets ? because there is no ordered set

Comment: Sorry for the terminology, I believe considering the inputs as sequences rather than sets would be appropriate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem has been studied under the name "maximum-weight non-crossing matching". There's a simple quadratic-time dynamic program. Let M(a, b) be the value of an optimal matching on n<sub>1</sub>, …, n<sub>a</sub> and m<sub>1</sub>, …, m<sub>b</sub>. We have the recurrence

> M(0, b) = -b
>   M(a, 0) = -a
>   M(a, b) = max {M(a - 1, b - 1) + match(a, b), M(a - 1, b) - 1, M(a, b - 1) - 1}.

By tracing back the argmaxes, you can recover an optimal solution from its value.

If match has significantly fewer than a quadratic number of entries greater than -1, there is an algorithm that runs in time linearithmic in the number of useful entries ([Khoo and Cong, A Fast Multilayer General Area Router for MCM Designs](http://fmdb.cs.ucla.edu/Treports/920011.pdf)).